# javascript: get first WORKDAY of next month

Tags: javascript, date

How can I write a function that returns the date object of the following month's first workday (monday through friday) without using Moment.js?
this code gets me the last businesss day of the month but i'd like to switch it to get me the first day of next month.

```
function lastBusinessDayOfMonth(year, month) {
var date = new Date();
var offset = 0;
var result = null;

if ('undefined' === typeof year || null === year) {
    year = date.getFullYear();
}

if ('undefined' === typeof month || null === month) {
    month = date.getMonth();
}

do {
    result = new Date(year, month, offset);

    offset--;
} while (0 === result.getDay() || 6 === result.getDay());

return result;
```

}

Comment: Could you share the code you've got so far?

Comment: Why woudn't you start with `1` as date and work upwards? you are going in wrong direction

Comment: Not all cultures start the week on a Monday, nor is it necessarily the first business day of the week. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If starting at an offset = 0 starts you at the last day of the month, then an offset of 1 will start you and the first day of the next month.  And instead of working backwards with a offset--, you work forwards with an offset++.

```
function lastBusinessDayOfMonth(year, month) {
var date = new Date();
var offset = 1;
var result = null;

if ('undefined' === typeof year || null === year) {
    year = date.getFullYear();
}

if ('undefined' === typeof month || null === month) {
    month = date.getMonth();
}

do {
    result = new Date(year, month, offset);

    offset++;
} while (0 === result.getDay() || 6 === result.getDay());

return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a date for the first of the month, and if it's a Sunday add one day, if it's a Saturday add two days.

You should also consider the name carefully. Not every Monday to Friday is a business day as some are holidays, and in many cultures and occupations the business week is not Monday to Friday.

```js
/*  Return first day in the following month that is Monday to Friday,
 *  or not Saturday or Sunday.
 * 
 *  @param {number|string} year - defaults to current year
 *  @param {number|string} month - defaults to current month
 *  @returns {Date} - first day of following month that is Monday to Friday
 */
function firstMonToFriNextMonth(year, month) {
  var d = new Date();
  d = new Date(Number(year)  || d.getFullYear(),
               Number(month) || d.getMonth() + 1,
               1);
  d.getDay() % 6? d : d.setDate((2 + d.getDay()) % 5);
  return d;
}

// No args
console.log(firstMonToFriNextMonth().toString());
// Year only
console.log(firstMonToFriNextMonth(2018).toString());
// Month only
console.log(firstMonToFriNextMonth(null, 1).toString());
// All of 2018
for (var i=1; i<13; i++) {
  console.log(firstMonToFriNextMonth(2018,i).toString());
}
```